# There is one error in each of the following projects ( I need to fix them )

Tags: c, debugging, hex, codeblocks, primes

There is one error in each of the following projects ( I need to fix them ). In the first project, the code doesn't work for large values of n, and in the second one I have no clue why the program isn't working as it should. The toDecimal function is working fine, the problem is if I want a 1-digit number to read, the program will stop and 10 will be shown on the screen :s. I'm asking for a little bit of help and optimization, thank you for your time.

```
//prints the number of primes <= n < 10^5
#include <stdio.h>

int primes[100000];
int main(void)
{
    int n, nrp = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int p=2; p<=n; p++)
    {
        if (primes[p]==0)
        {
            nrp++;
            for(int x=p*p; x<=n; x+=p)
                primes[x] = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("number of primes: %d", nrp);
    return 0;
}



//converts a hexadecimal number with k<=10 digits to decimal
#include <stdio.h>

int toDecimal(char c)
{
    if ( 'a' <= c && c <= 'f' )
        return c-'a'+10;
    if ( 'A' <= c && c <= 'F' )
        return c-'A'+10;
    if ( '0' <= c && c <= '9' )
        return c-'0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char c='x';
    int k = 0;
    long long nr = 0;
    printf("Number of digits: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&c);
        nr = 16*nr + toDecimal(c);
    }
    printf("\n%lld\n", nr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does `toDecimal` return if none of the conditions are true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first program `int x = p*p;` will overflow when `p` is big enough.

In the second one, your `scanf` is reading a newline character (`c = 10`) and your `toDecimal` function has no protection for invalid characters, so it's returning garbage data. The result is wrong for every input, no matter the number of digits. Using `scanf(" %c",&c);` instead (notice the whitespace) will fix it. This will make it ignore anything before the actual character. Either way you need to make some serious changes to the code to check for invalid inputs, plus there is no check for `nr` potentially overflowing if you input a big enough number.

Also please learn how to use a debugger. This took literally 5 seconds to figure out, enough time to set a breakpoint and step a couple of times.